# Собственная функция для list.append

Tags: python

Я новичок. Может кто знает,как правильно с помощью def описать метод list.append не используя данный метод в написании кода. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: покажите что у вас уже есть, чтобы было понятно от чего отталкиваться. вы пишите свой класс ? или вам просто нужно добавить в существующий список элемент ?

Comment: Да, в указываемый пользователем список добавлять вводимый элемент

Comment: Алеся, если вопрос закрыт, один из ответов можно отметить как решение.

Answer (score 4):

Для имитации `append` можно использовать свойство сложения списков:

```
def my_append(list_: list, element):
    list_ += [element]


list_ = [1, 2, 3]
my_append(list_, 4)
print(list_)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Я уже поняла, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не использовать `append` можно сделать так:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
inp = input('User input')
lst += [inp]
```

Comment: Так проще,что то я про это не подумала. Спасибо

Comment: А если допусти удалить нужно,через i -элемент? Не используя методы list

Comment: @Алеся это уже отдельный вопрос. но `lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]`

Answer (score 0):

Совсем правильно:-) так:

а) Заходите, например, сюда и видите исходник Python. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3a8c56295d6272ad2177d2de8af4c3f824f3ef92/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L10600.

б) Находите строчку 11440.

в) Начинаете анализ, что вам нужно переносить, а что нет. И думаете, как переделывать на Python.

При необходимости пользуейтесь документацией по С.

Но это не очень легко будет. Так что рассматривайте ответ, скорее, как расширитель знаний и средство впечатления преподавателя своей эрудицей, чем как практическую рекомендацию. С практической точки зрения переписывание исходника с С на Python не лезет ни в какие ворота.